# Chartist.js bar chart fill axis

Tags: javascript, css, chartist.js

Does anyone know if it's possible with Chartist.js to ensure a horizontal bar chart takes full width of the chart container?

If you look at the screenshot you can see that the gray bar does not take up the whole width, based on the examples I would have thought that the highest value data point in the series would be scaled to fill to the end of the chart (and the axis scaled accordingly).

See screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I spent the afternoon trying to achieve the same thing with some success.

In short, I created a simple plugin that, on creation, dynamically adjusts the bar width based on the `stepLength` property.

https://jsfiddle.net/traviss0/gg1oj35x/